# Android Studio Emulator screen dimensions scaled down and bugged

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I recently installed Android Studio Chipmunk, after a fresh install of Windows 10. The Emulator is very bugged for some reasons. It is very zoomed and icons are enlarged. I have tried reinstalling the emulator, different devices, and android studio itself, but nothing helps. I am yet to report the issue to developers. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Bug]